# Android: Speeding up display of (html-formatted) text

Tags: android, html, textview, stringbuilder, scrollview

My app uses a StringBuilder to assemble paragraphs of text which are then displayed in a TextView within a ScrollView.

The displaytext.xml layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
  <TextView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/display_text" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#000000"
      >
  </TextView>
</ScrollView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code that displays the StringBuilder object sbText is

```
    setContentView(R.layout.displaytext);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_text);
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(sbText.toString()));
```

This works OK, except that it gets very slow as the amount of text grows. For example, to display 50 paragraphs totalling about 50KB of text takes over 5 seconds just to execute those three lines of code.

Can anyone suggest how I can speed this up, please?

Comment: Do you know which call(s) in the last line line is creating the delay?  Ie. if you replace that line with 

Html.fromHtml(sbText.toString());
tv.SetText("Finished!");

Does it still take 5 seconds to print "Finished!"?

Comment: Yes. Splitting the line into two parts and putting Log calls before, in between and after indicates that it is the `Html.fromHtml(sbText.toString());` that takes all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest how I can speed this up, please?

Use a `WebView` instead of a `ScrollView` and `TextView`.

Also, as Nick indicated, confirm that the time you are spending really is being spent where you think it is, by using Traceview or something.

Comment: As I've said in response to Nick, LogCat indicates that the time is all taken in Html.fromHtml() (The setText() call, even with the 50KB HTML string as argument, is virtually instantaneous). Given this, would using WebView be any faster than ScrollView and TextView? (I'll go away now and see if I can learn how to use Traceview ...)

Comment: @prepbgg: `WebView` interprets and renders HTML using native C code. `Html.fromHtml()` is a fairly slow Java-based parser, designed for lightweight scenarios (e.g., tweets).

Comment: I wrote the following before I saw your last comment. I'll look at WebView now. Thanks. (To amplify my comment on the timings: using my specimen 50KB of text, with my original code the whole time taken to display the activity (according to ActivityManager in LogCat) is 5900ms. This includes reading in over 1MB of text, adding the extracted text to the StringBuilder and displaying the Activity. Removing the Html line and simply displaying the 50KB of unformatted text takes 1300ms. This seems to confirm that the process of converting to the Html class takes nearly 5 seconds.)

Comment: For the record, I've replaced the three lines of code in my original question with `WebView webview = new WebView(this); setContentView(webview); webview.loadData(text.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");` With this code there is no need for an xml layout file. The time taken to display my specimen 50KB of text is reduced to 2012ms. A very worthwhile reduction from the original 6 seconds! Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @prepbgg: If you let the `WebView` load the file, it will probably load even faster.

Comment: I need to analyse the content of the file and select lines for inclusion in the WebView. Also the reason I have used HTML is so that I can insert some text formatting. Hence, I need to read in the file first, then submit the selected, formatted text to the WebView.